# How to use the bisection method in boost C++ for a function with multiple arguments

Tags: c++, boost, bisection

I have below function in `C++`

```
#include <cmath>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/math/tools/roots.hpp>

double my_fn(double x, double y)
{
    return x*x - y - 1;
};

int main() {
    double min_x = 0.0;  // min value of domain of x
    double max_x = 10.0; // max value of domain of x
    double y = 1;

    // how to use boost's bisection to find solution of my_fn for y = 1
    return (0);
}
```

As you see `my_fn` takes 2 arguments `x` and `y`. However I want to find solution of this function given `y = 1`.

Can you please help to find solution using `bisection` method?

Comment: My actual search field is 1-dimensional, although my function has 2 arguments

Comment: oh sorry my fault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <cmath>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/math/tools/roots.hpp>

double my_fn(double x, double y)
{
    return x*x - y - 1;
};

int main() {
    double min_x = 0.0;  // min value of domain of x
    double max_x = 10.0; // max value of domain of x
    double y = 1;
    auto x = boost::math::tools::bisect(
            [y](double x){ return my_fn(x,y); },
            min_x,
            max_x,
            [](double x,double y){return abs(x-y) < 0.01;}
    );
    std::cout << "The minimum is between x=" << x.first << " and x=" << x.second;
    // how to use boost's bisection to find solution of my_fn for y = 1
    return (0);
}
```

`bisect` is a template. The first parameter is a callable (the function to minimize), then the initial bracket (min and max) and the last parameter is a callable that evaluates the stop condition.

Alternatively you can write a function:

```
double my_fn_y1(double x) {
    return my_fn(x,1);
}
```

and minimize that.

PS: The function does not return **the** solution, but rather the final interval which makes the stop condition true. The real solution is somewhere in that interval.

Comment: Many thanks. One more question - what if my function had 3 arguments viz. x, y, and z and I would fix y and z and search solution for x? I just want to generalise my problem

Comment: @Bogaso for 3 or more you do the same, no difference. just more captures of the lamda ( or more "defaults" in the wrapper function)

Comment: @Bogaso this is called [partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **lambda** (with good chance that the compiler inlines everything), like this:

```
#include <boost/math/tools/roots.hpp>
#include <iostream>
   
double my_fn(double x, double y) { return x * x - y - 1; };

int main()
{
  double min_x = 0.0;   // min value of domain of x
  double max_x = 10.0;  // max value of domain of x
  double y = 1;

  std::pair<double, double> result =
      boost::math::tools::bisect([y](double x) { return my_fn(x, y); },
                                 min_x,
                                 max_x,
                                 boost::math::tools::eps_tolerance<double>());

  std::cout << "Result " << result.first << ", " << result.second;

  return 0;
}
```

which prints:

```
Result 1.41421, 1.41421
```

You can read about lambda and lambda capture here: [cpp.reference lambda section](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).